# .desktop file not running application

Tags: 16.04, launcher, .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=FilterApp
Exec=python /home/ankit/Downloads/Filter_app-linux/run.py
Icon= /home/ankit/Downloads/Filter_app-linux/Pictures/filter.png
Name[en]=FilterApp
```

This is the content of my `Filter_app.desktop` file.

When I double click the icon, it comes to launcher bar, stays their for few seconds, then disappears. This isn't working clearly.

Also, the python file is running perfectly when i manually run that command from terminal.

I've tried seeing all possible answers on this website but none worked for me.

I tried making an example file named 'par.py' having content:-

```
import os
os.system('gnome-open Pictures/filter.png')
```

And a .desktop file for that namely 'var.desktop':-

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=FilterApp
Exec=python /home/ankit/Downloads/Filter_app-linux/par.py
```

This isn't working either. It seems like i'm missing something, but i don't know what.

**EDIT**:

When i run these desktop file with *dex* command, everything works fine.

Comment: What happens if you change the `Exec` line to `Exec=bash -c 'python /home/ankit/Downloads/Filter_app-linux/run.py'`?

Comment: @pomsky not working still. I don't know but the same .desktop file used to work. But now none is working. Read my  new edit too. It just seems problematic only when I try running them through double click.

Comment: @pomsky  is [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/nautilus-will-no-longer-launch-binaries.html) the probable reason?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this 16.04?

Comment: @doug its version of Ubuntu i'm using. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: Then the page you were reading about nautilus isn't applicable, it's only concerning recent nautilus releases. Tried your example here, works fine  in 16.04 though I use ubuntu session(unity), so no gnome-open, used xdg-open.  If you were to place your var.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications & then go this in a terminal are there any error messages? `gtk-launch var`

Comment: @doug  It isn't working still. I dunno how to run this through terminal. Whenever i try with `dex`, it runs perfectly. The problem is in running through double click .  Is it cache related problem, or something like that?